# Getting All Calendar SubFolders from CSV List of Users

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting, permissions, office365

I am trying to get a list of all the subfolders for a list of users from importing a CSV. Here is the code I have:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\177626\Desktop\Calendar.csv" | foreach {Get-MailboxFolder -identity "$($_.CalendarUsers):\Calendar" -GetChildren}
```

`$_.CalendarUsers` is what I am using as the column in the CSV for the user email addresses.

The issue is whenever I run the script, it reads the first users but then tell me any user after that, that the mailbox does not exist. See attached:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated to figure this out...also, is it possible to also list the User's Name and PrimarySMTP from the output of this script?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your input csv file is correct ? (_Comma_ as delimiter, no extra spaces around the usernames, etc.)

Comment: @Theo, Yeah I checked the CSV and it is saved as a .csv file and there are no spaces anywhere in the doc after or before the values.

Comment: So if you do `(Import-Csv "C:\Users\177626\Desktop\Calendar.csv").CalendarUsers` you get all correct usernames?

Comment: @Theo, Correct! I just ran that and am seeing the couple test usernames I have in the file.

Comment: Could it be a [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps) problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all the mailboxes and the calendars in the .csv file are provisioned.

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\177626\Desktop\Calendar.csv" | foreach {Get-Mailbox -identity $_.CalendarUsers}

Import-Csv "C:\Users\177626\Desktop\Calendar.csv" | foreach {Get-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity "$($_.CalendarUsers):\Calendar"}
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxcalendarfolder?view=exchange-ps